# Django app doesn't recognize .env file, I tried to set it up through the os, Django-environ, and dotenv but nothing worked

Tags: python, django

I set up a new django app in a virtual environment and tried to use a .env file with it for the secret key and the database url, however I can't manage to make the django app read the .env file.

I've tried first with os.environ, tried to set a direct path, tried with dotenv (both python-dotnev and django-dotnev, seperately) and last with Django-environ. I tried putting the .env file is in the same folder, the parent folder, the venv folder, but nothing worked.

In myapp/settings.py I have:

```
import os
import environ

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

And then in the same folder I have ".env" file:

```
Debug=True
SECRET_KEY='some-secret-key'
```

I tried adding "export" before Debug and SECRET_KEY but it didn't make any difference. I constantly get this error when I run python manage.py runserver:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

What am I missing? What step did I not do? Does it not work because the app runs in a virtual envirnoment?

Comment: can you show your project structure?